# Integrate Auth0 data with Freshsales CRM

Tags: authentication, integration, auth0

This seems simple, but it's not working for me. I'm trying to get the Auth0 identification data from our app to pipe into our Freshsales CRM to create a new contact. What is the best way to do this? I'm open to using a glueware service like Segment if that's really the easiest way, but I'm not sure it is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Auth0, you can use token and Freshsales APIs here. A token can be generated from your freshsales application(Under Personal Settings > API settings) and it can be used in contact creation API as mentioned here - https://developers.freshworks.com/crm/api/#create_contact